# QR code scanner fetching data, can't connect to mysql

Tags: android, android-volley

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (result != null) {
            if (result.getContents() == null) {
                Toast.makeText(this, " Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                resultQR(result.getContents());
            }
        } else {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }
```

Method sending QR code to server and receiving result :

```
void resultQR(final String dataQR) {
        try {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(dataQR);
            final Integer qrID = obj.getInt("id");

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, APIURL,
                    new Response.Listener<String>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(String response) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response);
                                if(!object.equals("0")) {

                                    int ID = object.getInt("id");
                                    if(qrID.equals(ID)){
                                        textViewName.setText(ID);
                                    }
                                }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Can't COnnect", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            error.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    });

            Volley.newRequestQueue(this).add(stringRequest);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(this,"Data Not Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

After scanning the qr it always go to "Can't Connect". The value of QR is `id` : `1`. I'm running on my phone the address is http://192.168.1.110/ . which is my ip address.

Comment: What is the error you are getting in the stack trace? Looking at this data is generally the easiest way to debug Android/Java applications. You could alternatively call your **toast** like this to see what the root cause is: **Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(error), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();** in your **ErrorListenser**, simply stating your code **"Can't Connect"** doesn't provide much insight into where your issues are

Comment: I'm trying to do is display the information of resultQR. @ViaTech

Comment: Do you receive anything to server side?

Comment: @bruno sorry for late reply. It didn't receive anything.